# Script to add and remove F-Curve Modifiers to multiple selected f-cruves

Tags: python, scripting, fcurves

I want to apply 'Cycles' modifier to multiple selected f-curves to create a  walk sequence. I want to do this with a script. How can I do this?

Comment: Would you also consider using   NLA action strip repeat?

Comment: To repeat with offset i have add f-curve modifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy
D = bpy.data
# We can access by action name
fcurves = D.actions['Goon_proxyAction'].fcurves
for f in fcurves :
    # TO add
    m = f.modifiers.new('CYCLES')
    #To remove
    f.modifiers.remove(m)
    # To remove all 'CYCLES' type modifiers
    for m in f.modifiers:
       if (m.type == 'CYCLES'): 
           f.modifiers.remove(m)
```